# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/users/add-user'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular6

So my problem is that I can't access the path '/dashboard/users/add-user' or any other route in users-routing.module.ts except the default (empty) route and I'm stuck with above mentioned error. Need some to escape this. Below is some necessary part of my code.

### app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', data: {title:'Dashboard'} },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard/transactions', pathMatch: 'full' },
]
```

### dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: 'users', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule',data:{title:'Users'} },
]
}]
```

### users-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path:'', component:UsersLandingComponent },
    { path:'add-user', component:AddUserComponent, pathMatch:'full', data:{title: 'Add User'}}
]
```

### dashboard.component.html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="accent">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks; let i = index" [routerLink]="link.path" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="activeLinkIndex === i"
  (click)="activeLinkIndex = i">{{link.label}}</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: add pathMatch: 'full' here { path:'', component:UsersLandingComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

Comment: @FatehMohamed not making any difference. UsersLandingComponent from path 'dashboard/users' is already accessible. But I can't access any other path other than this in users-routing.module.ts.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle??

Comment: @HardikPatel too much of code :|